# System Screen wording change crm 2013

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

When clicking the `Manage Members` button on a marketing list in 2013 we are prompted with a screen:

> Manage Members
>
> Choose how you want to find customers, and then add or
>   remove these as members to the marketing list
>
> How do you want to find members?

In our solution we have renamed the entity **Marketing List**

The question is how do we update this screen to change the wording and the following dialog `Manage Members -- Webpage Dialog` which also includes the marketing list phrase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice easy one :)

Solutions>Export Translation> edit CrmTranslation.xml> Find Replace all> re-import

Publish

Worked a charm

Answer (score 0):

We cannot, on CRM Online.

It's *possible* On-Premise, but any change is at risk of being lost every time a UR is applied. Not to mention that, obviously, anything you customize outside a supported customization is ... well, unsupported.

My gut tells me that this particular issue would be addressed in a UR, I'd go the ticketing route and get in touch with Microsoft itself.